# Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table6

Tags: mysql

First, I create the following table without any problem:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forecast`.`forecast_main_2` (
`ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data_carga` DATE NOT NULL,
`mes_ref1` DATE NOT NULL,
`mes_ref2` DATE NOT NULL,
`mes_ref3` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`tipo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

but when I tried creating the next:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forecast`.`forecast_labs_2` (
`ID_labs` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`sku` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`prev_m1_labs` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`prev_m2_labs` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`prev_m3_labs` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`forecast_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID_labs`, `forecast_id`),
INDEX `forecast_id_UNIQUE` (`ID_labs` ASC),
INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`forecast_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `ID`
FOREIGN KEY (`forecast_id`)
REFERENCES `forecast`.`forecast_main_2` (`ID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

The following error appears: "Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'forecast_labs_2'"

I really can't see where the duplicate key is. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Works fine on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c048b2) after removing the forecast schema references (build schema) what version of MySQL?

Comment: Your `CONSTRAINT ID` name probably already exists in your database. Either don't give it a name, or something that is a little less generic than `ID` (usually: something that contains the name of your table).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  Solarflare, it was exactly that. After I didnt name the constraint, it work just fine. Sorry if the question was simple, I'm still a beginner in SQL, but you helped a lot!